# Android linearLayout with 3 children. 2 of which are of equal width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearlayout with 3 children.

Two of them should have the same width. The one child in the middle should grow however it wishes. And the two equal width children should split the remaining space.

```
|<-- equal width --> <-- a gorwing child --> <-- euqal width -->|
```

How do I make such an arrangement with linearlayout?

Thanks

Comment: By using LinearLayout you won't be able to get your expected result as always. Instead of LinearLayout use RelativeLayout. Please see my answer below.

Comment: check out my answer with this solution you don't need to use another Layout.ViewGroup like linearLayout. so it 's more efficient for memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Middle Button Long Text " />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make the width of middle button `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

**Option 2**

i would suggest to use it ...use a Relative layout instead. With help of `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` you can achieve the layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="Left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt_left"
        android:text="Middle Button Long Text Middle Button Long Text Middle Button Long Text Middle Button Long Text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="Right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This is not true. By having this value set, if middle text increases then it'll overlap other 2 text views. And here weight of Middle text is not having meaning it'll produce same result with 0.1 weight

Comment: i am very eager to see ur version of the answer!! @Manmohan

Comment: then i hope i can do betterrr !

Comment: I'll rather go with updating layout params as per device size. For same can have custom view

Comment: `updating layout params as per device size` that's a rhetorical point..why not describe and add it in answer!

Comment: I think that here logic for implementing same is open now. And i believe that @user1017674 able to do from here.

Comment: I think your solution will not work always as per expected behavior. Try using short text like "one" in your middle button and see the output. Left and right button width remain fixed as their weight is 1 and the middle button width will large with center align text "one".

Comment: @FerdousAhamed yes i notice that already...that's not the problem...problem is if u add a long text in `YOUR`  `button_middle` it overlaps the left  and right button...thats the Problem..and pls check your answer rather than scratching on others

Comment: @rafsanahmad007: Good to know that. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:text="Button 1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:text="Button 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `LinearLayout` you won't be able to get your expected result as always. Instead of `LinearLayout` use `RelativeLayout`.

**Here is fully working code. Try this:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="MIDDLE GROWING" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="EQUAL" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="EQUAL WIDTH" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

> FYI, I have used 3 layout to make understand that its working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

put these wherever you want but change width and height to what you prefer

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/yyy"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/draw"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/zzz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/xxx"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/yyy"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_draw"/>
```

and actually it doesn't need LinearLayout or RelativeLayout but you can make them child to any group view but i recommend not to do it because my suggestion is more efficient for memory usage.